# Find how many numbers are there in the image of $f$ which are less than $2003$

Tags: functions, contest-math

If $f : \mathbb{Z^0} \to \mathbb{Z^0}$ such that $f(2n+1)^2 - f(2n)^2 = 6f(n) + 1$ and $f(2n)\geq f(n)$ $\forall$ $n\in \mathbb{Z^0}$, find how many numbers are there in the image of $f$ which are $< 2003$

It can be observed that $f(2n) < f(2n+1)$ and that $f(2n+1)±f(2n) \mid 6f(n)+1$. So one of $f(2n+1), f(2n)$ is odd for all $n$. That is, either the $f(2n)'$s or the $f(2n+1)'$s are always odd. Don't know how to proceed any further.

Comment: What is $\mathbb Z^0$?

Comment: $\mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specific problem prompt is a roundabout way to ask you what the function actually is.

It's good that you observed $f(2n) < f(2n+1) $ and that $f(2n + 1 ) - f(2n) $ is odd. These are crucial first steps.

**Hint:** Now prove the following (in order). These should be almost immediate.
 1. $f(2n+1) > f(2n)$.
 2. $f(2n+1) - f(2n)$ is odd.
 3. $f(2n+1) + f(2n) \geq 2f(n)+1$.

> $f(2n) \geq f(n), f(2n+1) > f(2n) \Rightarrow f(2n+1) \geq f(n) + 1$. Add them up.

4. $f(2n+1) - f(2n) < 3$.
5. $f(2n+1) - f(2n) = 1$.
6. $f(2n+1) + f(2n) = 6f(n) + 1$.
7. $f(2n) = 3f(n),$ and $ f(2n+1) = 3f(n) + 1$.
8. $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$.
9. $f(n) =$ evalute the binary representation of $n$ in trenary (base 3). E.g. $f(5) = f(101_2) = 101_3 = 10$.
10. Since $ 2003 = 2202012_3$, hence there are $1101011_2 = 107$ values of $n$ such that $f(n) < 2013$.

Comment: Could you please explain how the third claim can be proven? Additionally I believe it's supposed to be $2f(n)+1$ instead of $2n+1$

Comment: Typo fixed. __Hint__: Which condition in the question have you not used? Full details have been added.

Comment: Ah, how could I miss that! Thank you, I get it all now.